# Partial credit for numeric exercises (e.g. for guessing tasks)?

Tags: r, r-exams

I'm teaching students to visually approximate effect sizes from typical plot types (e.g. Pearson's *r* from scatter and parallel coordinates plots, Kendall's τ from alluvial plots, Cramer's *V* from mosaic plots, ...). Dynamic generation of such tasks with the `{exams}`package works like a charm.
However, as I use the questions generated with r-exams in moodle, and moodle allows to give partial credit for the *numeric question type*, I was wondering if there is a way to implement this via `{exams}`.
A possible function converting answers to partial credit could be

[image: formula]

Comment: Well, if you have the variables, that is just `MaxPoints * (1 - abs(TrueEffSize - GuessedEffSize)/RangeEffsize) * PenaltyFactor`

Comment: @dash2. That is true. But how to tell moodle via {exams}, that this is the partial credit?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think it is possible to use a continuous function for assigning partial credits in Moodle. But for `NUMERICAL` answers in Moodle cloze questions you can set discrete steps of partial credits, see the accompanying [Moodle docs](https://docs.moodle.org/310/en/Embedded_Answers_(Cloze)_question_type#Numerical_Cloze_questions).

R/exams currently has no convenience functionality for generating such partial credits for `cloze` questions with `num` elements. However, it is possible to put `verbatim` elements into the cloze where the `exsolution` contains the Moodle `NUMERICAL` syntax. See the [confint3](http://www.R-exams.org/templates/confint3/) exercise template for a worked example.

For doing something similar to what you describe, I have written a small convenience function `num_to_moodle()` which approximates the continuous function by a discrete step function. The syntax is `num_to_moodle(x, tol = 0, breaks = 1, range = NULL)` where:

- `x` is the correct solution,
- `tol` is the tolerance for 100% of the points,
- `breaks` is the number of additional steps towards 0% of the points, which are awarded beyond the maximum tolerance of `tol * breaks`,
- `range` is an optional range in which to consider the partial credits.

As an illustration I include a short exercise that displays a scatterplot and student have to "guesstimate" the correlation coefficient `r` (sampled in -0.9, -0.6, ..., 0.9). The numerical solution is set up as: `num_to_moodle(r, tol = 0.06, breaks = 5, range = c(-1, 1))`. That means `r` plus/minus 0.06 is accepted for 100% of the points, the next 0.06 (in both directions) for 80%, the next 0.06 for 60%, etc. Everything beyond plus/minus 0.3 yields 0%. Partial credit solution beyond -1 or 1 are excluded. (To be precise: Only midpoints outside that interval are excluded. Due to the tolerances solutions slightly outside might still yield points.)

[image: correlation exercise using partial credits via num_to_moodle()]

The source code for the `num_to_moodle()` function is:

```
num_to_moodle <- function(x, tol = 0, breaks = 1, range = NULL, digits = 5) {
  ## round correct solution and tolerance
  breaks <- round(breaks)
  x <- round(x, digits = digits)
  tol <- round(tol, digits = digits)

  ## only correct solution without tolerance
  if(breaks <= 0L || (breaks == 1L && tol <= 0)) return(paste0(":NUMERICAL:=", x))

  ## only correct solution with tolerance
  if(breaks == 1L) return(paste0(":NUMERICAL:=", x, ":", tol))

  ## multiple partial solutions with tolerances
  if(!(breaks %in% c(2:6, 10))) stop("'breaks' must be 0, 1, ..., 6, or 10")
  perc <- exams:::moodlePercent((breaks:1L)/breaks)
  y <- seq(x + 1.5 * tol, by = tol, length.out = breaks - 1L)

  ## set up Moodle string: :NUMERICAL:=solution1~solution2~solution3 etc.
  ## where each solution has: %_percent_%_solution_:_tolerance_#_comment_
  perc <- c("", paste0("%", rep.int(perc[-1], 2), "%"))
  x <- round(c(x, y, x + (x - y)), digits = digits)
  tol <- c(tol, rep.int(tol/2, 2 * (breaks - 1L)))
  if(!is.null(range)) {
    if(length(range) != 2L) stop("'range' must have length 2")
    ok <- (x >= range[1L]) & (x <= range[2L])
    if(!ok[1L]) stop("'x' is not within 'range'")
  } else {
    ok <- rep.int(TRUE, 2 * breaks - 1L)
  }
  num <- paste0(":NUMERICAL:=", paste0(
    perc[ok],        ## percents
    x[ok],           ## solutions
    ":", tol[ok],    ## tolerances
    "",              ## comments (none for now)
    collapse = "~")) ## collapse
  return(num)
}
```

The screenshot above has been generated based on:

```
set.seed(0)
exams2moodle("correlation.Rmd")
```

where the `correlation.Rmd` exercise contains the following text:

````
```{r, include = FALSE}
r <- sample(seq(-0.9, 0.9, by = 0.3), 1)
x <- rnorm(200)
y <- r * x + rnorm(200, sd = sqrt(1 - r^2))
r <- cor(x, y)
```

Question
========

Consider the following scatterplot:
\
```{r scatterplot, echo = FALSE, results = "hide", fig.height = 5, fig.width = 5, fig.path = "", fig.cap = ""}
plot(x, y)
```

Answerlist
----------
* Estimate the correlation of x and y:


Meta-information
================
exname: Correlation
extype: cloze
exclozetype: verbatim
exsolution: `r num_to_moodle(r, tol = 0.06, breaks = 5, range = c(-1, 1))`
````

Comment: Thanks @Achim for the clarification! Do you see a solution/workaround to generate **discrete** partial credits in moodle via R/exams numeric or verbatim questions?

Comment: I've included a worked example now. Feedback is welcome.

Comment: Coming back to this problem for the next midterm exams and facing a very convenient solution with `num_to_moodle()`. Especially the ability to set breaks *and* a range makes sense.